# Override default_nettype in ModelSim

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

I would like to change `default_nettype` in my RTL design without explicitly modifying the respective compiler directive within each file.

Is there a way to override it in ModelSim software?

Comment: in verilog you only need to add this directive to the very first file in the compilation list. Unless it gets overwritten in some other files, it will stick. Alternatively you can add it to a common \`include file if you have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is *no*.